# decompiling a bin file of protobufs-net

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-c

i have a serialized bin file of protobufs, written mainly in protobufs-net.
i want to decompile it, and see the structure of it.

i used some toolds like :
`https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode`

and i also used `protoc`:

`protoc --decode_raw < ~/Downloads/file.bin`

and this is part of the result i get:

```
1 {
  1: "4f81b7bb-d8bd-e911-9c1f-06ec640006bb"
  2: 0x404105b1663ef93a
  3: 0x4049c6158c593f36
  4: 0x40400000
  5 {
    1: "53f8afde-04c6-e811-910e-4622e9d1766e"
    2 {
      1: "e993fba0-8fc9-e811-9c15-06ec640006bb"
    }
    2 {
      1: "9a7c7210-3aca-e811-9c15-06ec640006bb"
      2: 1
    }
    2 {
      1: "2d7d12f1-2bc9-e811-9c15-06ec640006bb"
    }
    3: 18446744073709551615
  }
  6: 46
  7: 1571059279000
}
```

how i can decompile it? i want to know the structure and change data in it and make a new bin file.

Comment: well, which fields do you need to change? the simplest thing would be to create your own .proto that matches the flavor of the above, and deserialize/mutate/serialize

Comment: well i don't have any info about the program , i only have bin file, no other info

Comment: depending on the wire-types reported (varint vs fixed32 vs fixed64 etc) this looks like just a bunch of int32/string/etc with a repeated sub-message... do you have the actual bin?

Comment: Note: if you can't post the file here, but you can share it more privately, please feel free to email it to me and I can readily reverse-engineer a passable schema from it. It won't have the original names, and we won't know whether some fields are zig-zag etc, but: it'll round-trip fine, so should work for the purpose here

Comment: yes , it's exactly as you are saying (as i decompile it using that online tool). yes i have bin file , how can i send it to you ?

Comment: If it is small and not privileged: just post the hex or base-64 in the question. Otherwise again: email might be your best option (see my profile page).

Comment: i'll send it to you're gmail. thanks alot

Comment: i just sent it, thanks again

Comment: received, reverse engineered, and returned; I've done the same again here using **just** the data in the question (so it might not be as complete), for the benefit of others

Comment: Note that if you had the .exe or .dll that was generating these files, it is often possible to obtain the field names and other information from there.

Comment: thanks, i don't have access to code i only have serialized bin file.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse engineering a .proto file is mostly a case of looking at the output of the tools such as you've mentioned, and trying to write a .proto that looks similar. Unfortunately, a number of concepts are **ambiguous** if you don't know the schema, as multiple different data types and shapes share the same encoding details, but... we can make guesses.

Looking at your output:

```
1 {
...
}
```

tells us that our root message probably has a sub-message at field 1; so:

```
message Root {
    repeated Foo Foos = 1;
}
```

(I'm guessing at the `repeated` here; if the `1` only appears once, it could be single)

with everything at the next level being our `Foo`.

```
  1: "4f81b7bb-d8bd-e911-9c1f-06ec640006bb"
  2: 0x404105b1663ef93a
  3: 0x4049c6158c593f36
  4: 0x40400000
  5: { ... }
  6: 46,
  7: 1571059279000
```

this looks like it *could* be

```
message Foo {
  string A = 1;
  sfixed64 B = 2;
  sfixed64 C = 3;
  sfixed32 D = 4;
  repeated Bar E = 5; // again, might not be "repeated" - see how many times it occurs
  int64 F = 6;
  int64 G = 7;
}
```

however; those `sfixed64` could be `double`, or `fixed64`; and those `sfixed32` could be `fixed32` or `float`; likewise, the `int64` could be `sint64` or `uint64` - or `int32`, `sint32`, `uint32` or `bool`, and I wouldn't be able to tell (they are all just "varint"). Each option gives a different meaning to the value!

our `Bar` *definitely* has some kind of `repeated`, because of all the `2`:

```
    1: "53f8afde-04c6-e811-910e-4622e9d1766e"
    2 { ... }
    2 { ... }
    2 { ... }
    3: 18446744073709551615
```

let's guess at:

```
message Bar {
  string A = 1;
  repeated Blap B = 2;
  int64 C = 3;
}
```

and finally, looking at the `2` from the previous bit, we have:

```
      1: "e993fba0-8fc9-e811-9c15-06ec640006bb"
```

and

```
      1: "9a7c7210-3aca-e811-9c15-06ec640006bb"
      2: 1
```

and

```
      1: "2d7d12f1-2bc9-e811-9c15-06ec640006bb"
```

so combining those, we might guess:

```
message Blap {
    string A = 1;
    int64 B = 2;
}
```

Depending on whether you have more data, there may be additional fields, or you may be able to infer more context. For example, if an `int64` value such as `Blap.B` is *always* `1` or omitted, it might actually be a `bool`. If one of the `repeated` elements always has at most one value, it might not be `repeated`.

The trick is to to play with it until you can deserialize the data, re-serialize it, and *get the exact same payload* (i.e. round-trip).

Once you have *that*: you'll want to deserialize it, mutate the thing *you wanted to change*, and serialize.